# Sharing realtime data Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I am developing an Android application that will communicate with server via Websocket and that server will send real-time data. I would like to know about the best approach to share that data between activities and fragments ?

Architecture is the following:
First activity just runs a websocket client in a service that establishes the connection between android and a websocket server and receives data and then opens a second activity with some fragments where data is being displayed. I need to share data from the service to the second activity and update fragments.

I know that I can use IntentService to achieve this but I'd like to get an expert opinion whether that approach is a good one or not?
Probably, for such kind of a task android platform provides more elegant solution except IntentService.
Thanks!

Comment: Why not run the first "activity" as a service, and use that data to populate the second activity (as the new first)j?

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai because on the first activity I have som views to interact with a user . E.g. play button that runs a Websocket service and then starts the 2nd activity. That's why I am not sure that this approach is a good :( I am noob at android development